# Contains only working partially C#, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, contains

I have a drop down list of employees for a user to select. When a user selects an employee, I compare the value to what's in my database. If the selected value contains the first and last name of an employee, then I'm supposed to be able to pull their respective employee ID.

My problem is that I'm using .Contains, and it's only catching some employee names, even though they are all using the same casing and there's no way that there could be errors such as extra spaces because the list of employees is populated by the same table I'm comparing it to in order to find the IDs.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AppViewModel app, App appl, string selectedEmployee)
    {
        //Grabs the value of the selected employee.
        selectedEmployee = Request.Form["selectEmployee"].ToString();

        try
        {
            //TODO: Add insert logic here
            var emp = Database.Session.Query<Employee>().AsEnumerable();

            appl.AppOwnerID = (from e in emp
                               where selectedEmployee.Contains(e.EmpFirstName) && selectedEmployee.Contains(e.EmpLastName)
                               select e.EmplID).First();



            using (ITransaction transaction = Database.Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Database.Session.Save(appl);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
```

For some reason, when I select certain employees, it's able to find their IDs and it works perfectly, but for other employees it returns " " as it's value because the Contains method can't find their first and last name.

**UPDATE:** Here is where my list is created and populated. As all of you had mentioned using trim, I added the trim method for when I am adding objects in my list, along with adding it where I compare the selected value to the database values.

```
 // GET: App/Create
    public ActionResult Create(string selectEmployee)
    {
        //Holds all employees
        var emp = Database.Session.Query<Employee>().AsEnumerable();

        //Orders employees by last name.
        var empOrdered = emp.OrderBy(e => e.EmpLastName);


        //Formats Employees Names and creates array
        var empName = (from e in empOrdered
                       select e.EmpFirstName + " " + e.EmpLastName).ToArray();

        //List to hold employee names
        var empList = new List<string>();

        //Loops through array to add names into list
        foreach (string empl in empName)
        {
            empList.Add(empl.Trim());
        }

        ViewBag.selectEmployee = new SelectList(empList);

        var model = new AppViewModel();

        return View(new AppViewModel());
    }
```

**Second Update:** Here's my view to go along with the controller.

```
 @model App_Catalog.Models.AppViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>AppViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Owner, htmlAttributes: new { @class =      "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("selectEmployee", "Please Select an Employee")
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Could it be you're misunderstanding the usage of `First()`?  Also, what is the purpose of the line `selectedEmployee = Request.Form["selectEmployee"].ToString();`?

Comment: are you absolutely certain that the employee names selected are the exact same as what is in the DB? If you run an SQL query against the database directly, do you get similar results?

Comment: why are you not using Where instead of Contains ? i.e also what in selectedEmployee  , what are you getting from dropdown list?

Comment: How often does this refresh?  "var emp = Database.Session.Query<Employee>().AsEnumerable();"

Comment: @Matthew: That line is supposed to grab the value that the user selected from the drop down list. So that variable holds the employee's name.

Comment: @Sadaquat: I am using where in my linq statement.

Comment: @Casper: The list is populated in the Http Get method using that same line of code to get all of the employees from the database. So I imagine it refreshes every time the user accesses the page

Comment: @user1666620: The employee names selected should be exactly the same as what is in the DB. I'm pulling from the DB to populate the list.

Comment: @Matthew: My understanding of First() is that it selects the first value that satisfies a criteria. Is that not what First() does?

Comment: @bongo700 it is, but the question has some conflicting information, such as `it returns a null value` and `catching some employee names`.  `First()` will throw an exception if it doesn't find anything, which isn't what your question is stating.

Comment: @Matthew I apologize for not being clear. When I debug the controller to see what values are being passed when I use .Contains, it shows that it's passing " ".  An exception is thrown but only when I try to update the database.

Answer (score 2):

First - change your `Controller` signature to this:

```
public ActionResult Create(AppViewModel app, App appl, string selectEmployee)
```

When you do it MVC automaticaly bind `selectEmployee` variable and you don't need this string anymore:

```
//Grabs the value of the selected employee.
selectedEmployee = Request.Form["selectEmployee"].ToString();
```

About your query I belive that you're trying to do this:

```
appl.AppOwnerID = emp.FirstOrDefault(e => selectEmployee.Contains(e.EmpFirstName)
                  && selectEmployee.Contains(e.EmpLastName)).EmplID;
```

As all already said here - could be that you have some spaces in your employe name and last name. Use [`Trim()`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjSwMWGobrHAhVCl3IKHb4FDow&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fru-ru%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.string.trim(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=giTXVdL3AsKuygO-i7jgCA&usg=AFQjCNFeqmKwaRaFCwZvGHybzrMwOxtgbA&sig2=lFoy7OTaMpGwLnirhg58EA&cad=rjt) function to make sure that it's not your problem.

```
appl.AppOwnerID = emp.FirstOrDefault(e => selectEmployee.Contains(e.EmpFirstName.Trim())
                  && selectEmployee.Contains(e.EmpLastName.Trim())).EmplID;
```

Comment: For some reason, I can't get the lambda expression to work. I don't know enough about lambdas to troubleshoot it myself. I'm getting an error on the .Select portion that says my model does not contain a definition for "Select". Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Unfortunately, that didn't work either though.

Comment: @bongo700 do you check in debug what comes to comes to controller? Also i just can't undestand what are you doing in this line `Database.Session.Query<Employee>().AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: That line queries my employee table in the database to grab all of the values. I have an Employee model that is mapped to that table. When I debug the controller, it shows the value " " being passed, instead of an employee's name. As I've mentioned in my original post, when I select certain employees, it does actually pass their name as a value but for other employees, it passes " ". There lies my confusion.

Comment: @bongo700 ok, seems to be that problem on client side, show your view please

Comment: @bongo700 i can't see autocomlete script on your view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87612/discussion-between-bongo700-and-teo-van-kot).

Answer (score 0):

What about validating your Contains against lowercase values? 
For example (could be optimized code) as follows:

```
 where selectedEmployee.ToLowerCase().Contains(e.EmpFirstName.ToLowerCase()) &&
       selectedEmployee.ToLowerCase().Contains(e.EmpLastName.ToLowerCase())
```

Comment: I tried using ToLower() like you said, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps trim your `e.EmpFirstName` and `e.EmpLastName` fields as they could be padded with whitespace. I have seen this many a time and it can cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: I tried trimming it but it's still passing a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove all whitespace and trim both sides on every string you which to check before you check the database.

```
selectEmployee = selectEmployee.Replace(" ", "").Trim();
```

And do the same to the records you pull from the database before you try and match them using contains.